# What does [byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0} mean in powershell ?

Tags: python, format, shellcode

I want add some powershell code in python,but meet '%{0}'in powershell when I use format function，then can't compile python.So I want to know the mean to change my code

Answer (score 0):

The double dot `..` is a range constructor.  `0..65535` will return an array of integers from 0 to 65535.  The percent sign after a pipe `|%` is shorthand for `foreach-object` after the pipe.

In this case, your powershell function

```
[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0}
```

Creates an array called `bytes` of type `byte` that has 65536 zeros for its values.

If you are trying to call this from Python using the string `format` function, then your will need to escape the curly brackets by doubling them.  For instance, if you wanted to use Python to adjust the variable name, you would use:

```
# in Python:
powershell_cmd = '[byte[]]${} = 0..65535|%{{0}}'.format('bytes')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I change my powershellcode as [byte[]]$bt=0..65535|%{{0}},but powershellcode seem don't have the same mean as before and  get the wrong result